# How to use RowCounter for counting rows in Hbase Table

Tags: hbase

I'm new to this technology. I need to count rows of large tables. I read here on internet about the method RowCounter. But I'm unable to implement it. Can anyone tell me the detailed steps involved in counting rows using RowCounter. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the hbase cmd, Java API, etc?

Comment: I think the answer you're looking for may be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227462/using-rowcounter-in-hbase-table). It is not marked as the correct answer but the comment on the answer given suggests it was the correct solution

Comment: Hello Douglas, I'm using he hbase cmd. I've already seen the link which you have mentioned. But, it gives Service Unavailable error when I click on it.

Comment: get complete exception along with stacktrace. might be helpful for us to identify the issue.